# How to Chain Left Join in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to perform a chained left join in MongoDB. I can use `$lookup` to join from `users` collection to `employee` collection. But if I want to join one more time with the `title` it will fail, in another word the the 2nd `.aggregate([{ $lookup }])` fails. The objective of this exercise is to display that John is using title prefix Mr. and Jane is using title prefix Mrs. while using an intermediary collection called employee. So how do I do that, or what did I do wrong?

```
db.users.drop();
db.users.insert({name:"John"});
db.users.insert({name:"Jane"});

db.title.drop();
db.title.insert({prefix:"Mr."});
db.title.insert({prefix:"Mrs."});

db.getCollection('users').find({});
db.getCollection('title').find({});

db.employee.drop();
db.employee.insert({userid:ObjectId("5d6522449b9bc50473af4b4f"), titleid:ObjectId("5d6522449b9bc50473af4b51")});
db.employee.insert({userid:ObjectId("5d6522449b9bc50473af4b50"), titleid:ObjectId("5d6522449b9bc50473af4b52")});
db.getCollection('employee').find({});

db.users.aggregate
([{
   $lookup:
     {
       from: 'employee',
       localField: '_id',
       foreignField: 'userid',
       as: 'R'
     }
   },
]).aggregate
([{
   $lookup:
     {
       from: 'title',
       localField: '_id',
       foreignField: R[0].titleid,
       as: 'T'
     }
   },
]);
```

Comment: You can use multiple lookup stages in the same pipeline. Please refer my answer.

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing wrong here is appending another query to the result of first query which will not work.

In my opinion you should write aggregate on employee collection rather than users collection which will look cleaner.

Anyway, I've written the correct query based on your question, and have aggregated on users collection

try this:

```
db.users.aggregate([
{$lookup: {
    from: "employee",
    localField: "_id",
    foreignField: "userid",
    as: "R"
}},
{$unwind: "$R"},
{$lookup: {
    from: "title",
    localField: "R.titleid",
    foreignField: "_id",
    as: "T"
}},
{$unwind: "$T"},
{$project: {name: 1, title: "$T.prefix", _id: 0} }
])
```

This will output documents like:

```
{ "name" : "John", "title" : "Mr." }
{ "name" : "Jane", "title" : "Mrs." }
```

The last $project stage is optional. You can omit it but then output will be pretty messy.

Answer (score 0):

The following query can get us the expected output:

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup:{
            "from":"employee",
            "localField":"_id",
            "foreignField":"userid",
            "as":"employeeLookup"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind:"$employeeLookup"
    },
    {
        $lookup:{
            "from":"title",
            "localField":"employeeLookup.titleid",
            "foreignField":"_id",
            "as":"titleLookup"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind:"$titleLookup"
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "_id":0,
            "name":{
                $concat:[
                    "$titleLookup.prefix",
                    " ",
                    "$name"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

**Data set:**

users:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d6525f922a848de552bdcf6"), "name" : "John" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d6525fa22a848de552bdcf7"), "name" : "Jane" }
```

title:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d6525fa22a848de552bdcf8"), "prefix" : "Mr." }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d6525fb22a848de552bdcf9"), "prefix" : "Mrs." }
```

employee:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d65265422a848de552bdcfa"),
    "userid" : ObjectId("5d6525f922a848de552bdcf6"),
    "titleid" : ObjectId("5d6525fa22a848de552bdcf8")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d65265422a848de552bdcfb"),
    "userid" : ObjectId("5d6525fa22a848de552bdcf7"),
    "titleid" : ObjectId("5d6525fb22a848de552bdcf9")
}
```

**Output:**

```
{ "name" : "Mr. John" }
{ "name" : "Mrs. Jane" }
```